# Non-pagebreaking return in LyX

Tags: lyx, line-breaking, page-breaking

I know that in TeX, I can issue `\\*` to make a new line without a page break. How I do that in LyX?

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't immediately look like there is support for that in the GUI, but you can always add it in an ERT. Insert --> TeX code, or shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.

Comment: Looks like it, which will make LyX unable to show the linebreak and show it all on one line.

Comment: @jonallard indeed. You might want to make a feature request for this at http://www.lyx.org/trac . I think it would be easy to add this functionality.